# How to handle client shutdown using threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, server, network-programming

I am new to Socket programming, My use case is to add shutdown message in my code that if one of the clients goes off or interrupted or killed then my server easily update the count or kill that thread.

```
import socket
import SSL
import testThread

context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_cert_chain(certfile=self.server_cert, keyfile=self.server_key)
context.load_verify_locations(cafile=self.ca_cert)

# to add threads
t = []  
# to store addresses
totalAddress = [] 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((self.TCP_IP, self.TCP_Port))
s.listen(4)

while True:
    print "Waiting for connections from TCP clients..."
    (conn, (ip, port)) = tcpServer.accept()
    print("Client connected: {}:{}".format(ip, port))
    conn = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_side=True)
    newthread = testThread.TestThread(ip, port, conn)
    newthread.start()
    t.append(newthread)
    totalAddress.append((ip,port))
    count = newthread.count() -1
    print "[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {} and number of clients running {}".format(totalAddress, count)
```

I have created count() in testThread.py file.

import threading
from datetime import datetime
import time

class TestThread(Thread):

```
def __init__(self, ip, port, conn):
   # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.ip = ip
    self.port = port
    self.conn = conn
    print "[+] New server socket thread started for " + ip + ":" + str(port)
```

")

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        data = self.conn.recv(2048)
        now = datetime.now()
        data = str(now) + " - " + data
        #print "Server received data:", data
        f = open("demofile.txt", "a")
        f.write(data)
    f.close()
```

Please excuse me if there is an error in the code. :)

Comment: Please edit your question to say exactly what specific error/issue the current code has, you can't just ask for a code review. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, the code should run standalone, you need to add the missing imports; also this one has 'self' references but seems like an excerpt from class. Please make your example run standalone.

Comment: @smci Done, let me know if still, it is missing

Comment: C-style '//' comments aren't legal Python, you can't have run it. Python comments start with '#'. And you're still missing `import` statements for `socket`, `tcpServer`, where do `context` and `testThread ` come from...?! Please fix all this stuff and test it in a clean Python shell.

Comment: Deepak: okay, that's what is meant on SO by "code examples must be [mcve]". You're still missing most of your `testThread.py` file, it has to define `testThread.TestThread`

Comment: @smci ok sure, hope this is enough now